# Solution to second order PDE with boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let's say I have this second order PDE as follow,
$$2u''_{xx}-5u''_{xy}+2u''_{yy}=0,$$
with the following conditions,
\begin{align}
u(x,1)&=x^2+4x+4+\sin⁡(x+1/2),\\
u(0,y)&=4y^2+\sin⁡(y/2),\\
u(0,0)&=0.
\end{align}
Of course this PDE is easy to solve and I obtain the solution,
$$u(x,y)=f(x+2y)+g(x+y/2).$$

The only problem is that I cannot really figure out to find the solution **with** the boundary condition and if I try to find it by Maple, nothing happens, i.e. Maple just stop computing. Any suggestion would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(x+2)^2 + \sin(x+ \frac 12)=u(x,1) = f(x+2) + g(x+ \frac 12)$$
leads to the hypothesis that $f(z) = z^2$ and $g(z) = \sin(z)$ could be the right solution.
$$0=u(0,0) = f(0) + g(0)$$
matches with that and
$$4y^2 + \sin(\frac y2) = u(0,y) = f(2y) + g(\frac y2)$$
also matches with that so our solution is
$$u(x,y) = (x+2y)^2 + \sin(x+\frac y2)$$

To be honest, this was not a very systematic approach. I just wrote down the boundary conditions - and from the first one there was a very clear pattern that just seemed to nice not to be tried and it worked.

Comment: Waow, why did I not think that way... Thanks for making this clear for me!